# Why should I use setInitParameter() instead of setAttribute() for ServletContext?

Tags: java, servlets, servletconfig

If I had to define a *context-visib* parameter at runtime, I wouldn't use `ServletContext.setInitParameter()` because init parameters are defined in the deployment descriptor once for all, and I suppose that `ServletContext().setAttribute()` would be more appropriate.

Said that,

1. is my approach correct? In which case should I use `ServletContext.setInitParameter()` instead of `ServletContext().setAttribute()`?
2. why is the method called `setInitParameter()`? *Init parameters* are actually defined for `ServletConfig` in the *web.xml* file, I'm setting/getting *context parameters* (owning to `ServletContext`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, your approach is correct. Using `ServletContext::setAttribute` is the correct way to do what you're doing. If you look at the javadoc for `ServletContext::setInitParameter`, you'll see it says:

> IllegalStateException - if this ServletContext has already been initialized

So once the context has started up, you won't be able to call that method any more.

2. `setInitParameter` was introduced with Servlet 3.0, which introduces annotation-based config as an alternative to XML config. I assume this method was added to allow annotation-based config to populate the init params via a Java method call.

Comment: At this point I'm a bit confused... Inside a Servlet i can call *getServletContext().setInitParameter("e-mail","e-mail@email.com")* without getting an exception, but isn't the context already initialized at that stage?